# Android gallery fling

Tags: android

I'm using gallery view to display list of images images in full screen, when I scroll the view, It scrolling so fast. So I override gallery onTouch mentod

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // swipe horizontal?
            if(Math.abs(deltaX) > 100){
                // left or right
                if(deltaX < 0) { 

                    //this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                    return true; 
                    }
                if(deltaX > 0) { 
                    Animation slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
                    this.mGallery.startAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    //this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                    picPosition = picPosition + 1;
                    Animation slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
                    this.mGallery.startAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    mGallery.setSelection(picPosition, true);

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I use this snippet, Its display image one by one but scrolling is looking very strange. I don't know how to achieve this with smooth scrolling. I'm struggling  more, anyone help out from this please...

Answer (score 4):

Try the code below, you basically have to override the `onFling()` method in Gallery.

```
public class CustomGallery extends Gallery
{
    public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);  
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { 
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, 0, velocityY); 
    }
}
```